# Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in ...\functions\node_modules\firebase\package.json

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase

**I'm trying to deploy this function, and getting this error, can someone please help?**
Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in C:\Users\op23238\PepmateFinal\pepmate-functions\functions\node_modules\firebase\package.json

```html
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const app = require("express")();

admin.initializeApp();
// // Create and deploy your first functions

// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started
const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};
const firebase = require("firebase");
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


//Sign up route
app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    const newUser = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
        handle: req.body.handle    
    };
    //TODO Validate data
  
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)
    .then(data => {
        return res.status(201).json({ message: `user ${data.user.uid} signed up successfully`});
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json( { error: err.code })
    });
});


exports.api = functions.region("asia-south1").https.onRequest(app);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L60qm.png)